# Trace of matrices is equal to zero or one

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, trace, symmetric-matrices

I want to prove that if matrices $E_{i,j}$ in $\mathbb{K}^{m,n}$ are matrices with all zeros except for one 1 on the $i,j$ index, then $\text{tr}((E_{i,j})^TE_{k,l})$ equals $1$ if $E_{i,j}=E_{k,l}$ and 0 in other cases.
I have an intuition that this is true but I don't know how to formally prove it.

Comment: Given a matrix $(a_{ij})_{1 \leq i,j \leq n}$ then $\operatorname{tr}(a_{ij}) = \sum_1^n a_{ii}$. You have to observe what is the result of the product $E_{i,j}^TE_{k,l}$ (write the product using the formal definition) and so, apply the definition of trace.

Comment: I know how to find trace but the problem is I'm not  sure how to find the formula for the product @Corrêa

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Definition for instance.

Comment: Is it right to say that $(E_{i,j})^TE_{k,l}$ equals $0$ when  $i\neq k$ and equals 
$E_{j,l}$ when $i=k$? And should it be specified that the result has other dimentions? Thank you for your help @Corrêa

Answer (score 0):

Given a matrix $A \in {\rm Mat}(n\times m, \Bbb R)$, let $\widetilde{A} \in \Bbb R^{nm}$ be the vector whose entries are the entries of $A$, listed row after row. You can show (using the definitions of trace and matrix multiplication) that ${\rm tr}(A^TB)$ equals the inner product of $\widetilde{A}$ and $\widetilde{B}$ in $\Bbb R^{nm}$. Very obviously the matrices $E_{ij}$ correspond to the standard basis of $\Bbb R^{nm}$, and the standard basis is orthonormal.